# Where does the Windows 8 Dropbox App store its files?

Tags: windows-8, dropbox, windows-store-app

Where does the Windows 8 Dropbox App store its files? I mean the user files, not the program files.

I want an answer for the App, not the desktop version.

Comment: In the cloud of course!

Comment: Do you mean the data which is downloaded from your Dropbox? If yes then it's probably stored in the AppData directory.